# Is there a way to modify the frequency of upload_file Callback?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using boto3 (Python).  Here's a sample call:

`s3.upload_file(file_name, s3_bucket, s3_bucket_key, Callback=update_progress, Config=config)`

The issue is that no matter what, the Callback is called 4 times per Mb.  So, basically every 256k it's called.  That's annoying for most progress tracking libraries.

The [official docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/upload_file.html) for this function say:

> Callback (function) – A method which takes a number of bytes transferred to be periodically called during the upload.

The issue is "...a number of bytes".  How can this be modified?  If it can't be, is there an open GitHub issue regarding this weird behavior?

I tried changing around the settings in the `TransferConfig` like the chunk size.  It makes no difference at all.  The frequency of the Callback's execution has nothing to do with chunk size or anything else in that config, from what I can tell.

Comment: "That's annoying for most progress tracking libraries" This seems to be the root of the issue you're facing.  Why would number of bytes be wrong?  You have the `file_name` you can easily determine the size of the file, and then update the progress bar accordingly.  What's the problem - too many updates to your UI?

Comment: @erik258 The number of bytes is not "wrong", it simply cannot be changed.  I see your point that I can work around it with a counter and only update, say, every 4th time if I want to update every Mb.  Still, is this REALLY not configurable?  Why?

Comment: It's called every time an IO chunk is complete, so pass `Config=TransferConfig(io_chunksize=1048576)` into your call to upload the file if you want it called every megabyte.